# Iterating through map and showing table

Tags: clojure, tabular

The first thing I want to say is that I am new to clojure, secondly I want to ask you how to iterate through a map and show all elements in a table? Here is what I have done.
This is my map-

```
(def kvote(assoc kvote (keyword kljuc){:id id :liga liga :dan dan :cas cas :domaciTim    domaciTim :gostujuciTim gostujuciTim :par par :konacanIshod{:1 jedinica :x nerijeseno :2 dvojka}}))
```

I was using cldwalker table function and did this...

```
(table [ ["liga" "dan" "cas" "id" "par" "1" "X" "2"] [(:liga(get kvote(keyword :101)))
                                                     (:dan(get kvote(keyword :101)))
                                                      (:cas(get kvote(keyword :101)))
                                                    (:id(get kvote(keyword :101))) 
                                                    (:par(get kvote(keyword :101)))
                                                      (get-in kvote [:101 :konacanIshod :1])
                                                      (get-in kvote [:101 :konacanIshod :x])
                                                      (get-in kvote [:101 :konacanIshod :2])
                                                     ]] )
```

the result is something like this...

```
+---------+---------+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+-----+---+
| liga    | dan     | cas   | id  | par                | 1   | X   | 2 |
+---------+---------+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+-----+---+
| Serie A | nedelja | 20:00 | 101 | Bologna - Cagliari | 1.5 | 2.3 | 4 |
+---------+---------+-------+-----+--------------------+-----+-----+---+
```

How can I iterate through the map and show all the elements, not only one by the specific keyword? Can I somehow increment my keyword value and show it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps implement the `Seq` interface, meaning you can use all these useful higher-order functions like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, ... to process them. The important part here is that the sequential representation of a map consists of `[key value]` vectors, e.g.:

```
(seq {:a 0 :b 1})
;; => ([:a 0] [:b 1])

(map (fn [x] (inc (second x))) {:a 0 :b 1})
;; => (1 2)
```

(If you do not know what `map` & co. do, read up on them - you will love them (eventually)!)

Now, in your case you're only interested in the values, not the keys, it seems, so `vals` will retrieve them for you:

```
(vals {:a 0 :b 1})
;; => (0 1)

(map inc (vals {:a 0 :b 1}))
;; => (1 2)
```

Your values, however, are maps themselves and you want to access certain keys in said maps and put them into a single vector/list. You can do that!

```
(map
  (fn [x]
    [(:key-1 x) (:key-2 x) ...])
  (vals your-map-of-maps))
```

This looks tedious. But creating the inner result is nothing else then looking up each one of a list (!) of keys in a hash map, so another use case for fancy higher-order `map`:

```
(map 
  (fn [x]
    (map (fn [k] (k x)) [:key-1 :key-2 ...]))
  (vals your-map-of-maps))
```

Now, actually Clojure makes it really easy to apply different functions (keywords are functions!) to the same value to obtain a list of results - `juxt` is what it's called, taking a series of functions and producing a new one that does exactly what I just described.

```
(def inc-and-dec (juxt inc dec))
(inc-and-dec 1)
;; => [2 0]
```

And here we go for maps:

```
((juxt :a :b) {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2})
;; => [0 1]
```

Okay, that's a lot to process but you'll only be able to work efficiently with Clojure if you understand what tools it offers you - and higher-level functions are probably those you'll use the most. Finally, let us create a table:

```
(table
  (cons
    ["header-1" "header-2" ...]
    (map (juxt :key-1 :key-2 ...) (vals your-map-of-maps))))
```

And now for the grand finale, cleaning up using threading macros!

```
(->> your-map-of-maps
     (map (juxt :key-1 :key-2 ...))
     (cons ["header-1" "header-2" ...])
     (table))
```

Yup, there's a lot Clojure can do, and sequences + higher-order-functions are a very powerful combination. And they still solve practical problems like creating a table!

Comment: this does the trick for me,but i cant use the values from the key :konacanIshod(:1 :x :2) because it contains map...how can i add the values from this key?

Comment: `comp` let's you compose functions. `(comp f g)` creates a function that first applies g to its arguments, then f to the result of g. This means, `(comp :a :b)` is a function that does `(get-in ... [:b :a])`. So, long story short, use `(juxt ... (comp :1 :konacanlshod) ...)`.

Comment: just what i needed,tnx.